# How to set image height same as its parent within TopAppBar jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm using an image within `TopAppBar` in jetpack compose. I've done it and its working fine. The problem is that i want to set the height of the image within the `TopAppBar` as the same height of the `TopAppBar`.

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo),
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            })
        }
    ) {  
    // rest code
}
```

Second Question: Please tell how to center the actions icons vertically within the `TopAppBar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
            title = {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(1.0f),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo),
                contentDescription = null
            )
})
```

Here image will take the height of the parent's height which is TopAppBar in this case.